# Why does `ng-repeat` on filtered dictionary cause `10 $digest() iterations reached` error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary

Consider the following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/awvCLgWsnXo9W3uKcwBk?p=preview)

Here is the `html`

```
    <div ng-repeat="(id, testOject) in filterList()">
      <div ng-if="testOject['state']">
        {{testObject}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the relevant `js`

```
  $scope.test = {
    '1': {'state': true, 'label': '1'}
  }

  $scope.filterList = function() {
    var map = {};

    for (var key in $scope.test){
      if($scope.test[key]['state']) {
        map[key] = {
          'state': $scope.test[key]['state'],
          'label': $scope.test[key]['label']
        }
      }
    }
    return map;
  };
```

The above code causes `10 $digest() iterations reached` error.

However if we modify the [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/LYVTRNw8ExbcKwRG7fCw?p=preview) a bit.

```
  $scope.filterList = function() {
    var map = {};

    for (var key in $scope.test){
      if($scope.test[key]['state']) {
        map[key] = true
      }
    }
    return map;
  };
```

The error doesn't occur

It seems like change detection is fired, when a new `key` that contain a brand new object is updated, but I have only 1 object in the dictionary, why does it loop through change detection 10 times?

Comment: Digest will be executed, while your scope changes. Filter should return same objects/arrays if data already filtered, not newly created.

Answer (score 2):

[From error page](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:8,%22oldVal%22:7%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:9,%22oldVal%22:8%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:10,%22oldVal%22:9%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:11,%22oldVal%22:10%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:12,%22oldVal%22:11%7D%5D%5D):

> This error occurs when the application's model becomes unstable and
>   each `$digest` cycle triggers a state change and subsequent `$digest`
>   cycle. Angular detects this situation and prevents an infinite loop
>   from causing the browser to become unresponsive.
>
> For example, the situation can occur by setting up a watch on a path
>   and subsequently updating the same path when the value changes.

```
 $scope.$watch('foo', function() {
      $scope.foo = $scope.foo + 1;
    });
```

> One common mistake is binding to a function which generates a new
>   array every time it is called. For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in getUsers()">{{ user.name }}</div>

...

$scope.getUsers = function() {
  return [ { name: 'Hank' }, { name: 'Francisco' } ];
};
```

> Since `getUsers()` returns a new array, Angular determines that the
>   model is different on each `$digest` cycle, resulting in the error. The
>   solution is to return the same array object if the elements have not
>   changed:

```
var users = [ { name: 'Hank' }, { name: 'Francisco' } ];

$scope.getUsers = function() {
  return users;
};
```

> The maximum number of allowed iterations of the $digest cycle is
>   controlled via TTL setting which can be configured via
>   [$rootScopeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$rootScopeProvider).

**For your case, you can use following code:**

[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/MC6DyOkB16hGbqUtY99X?p=preview)

```
  var map = {};
  $scope.createArray = function() {       

    for (var key in $scope.test){
      if($scope.test[key]['state']) {
        map[key] = {
          'state': $scope.test[key]['state'],
          'label': $scope.test[key]['label']
        }
      }
    }
    return map; 
  };

  $scope.filterList = function() {
      return map; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)

```
The $digest loop keeps iterating until the model stabilizes
```

i.e. the digest will stop when your model no longer changes between 2 consecutive cycles.

The code:

```
    map[key] = {
      'state': $scope.test[key]['state'],
      'label': $scope.test[key]['label']
    }
```

assigns a new object to `map[key]` on every digest cycle so the model is never stabilised.

The code:

```
map[key] = true
```

assigns a primitive boolean to `map[key]` that does not change between 2 consecutive digest cycles so the model becomes stable.

To stabilise your map, you can create a scope variable and just change he attributes of the `map[key]` object. See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rUvAy8O8co464OWTKJem?p=preview)

```
  $scope.map = {};

  $scope.filterList = function() {
    for (var key in $scope.test){
      if($scope.test[key]['state']) {
        $scope.map[key] = $scope.map[key] || {};
        $scope.map[key].state = $scope.test[key]['state'];
        $scope.map[key].label = $scope.test[key]['label'];
      }
    }

    return $scope.map;
  };
```

Comment: But it only changes once, since my dictionary is size one, so it should be within 10 cyles limit?

Comment: @testing I am not referring to `for (var key in $scope.test)`. I'm referring the the digest cycle. So cycle 1, filterList() is called and `$scope.map['1'] = newObject`. Cycle 2, filterList() is called and `$scope.map['1'] = anotherNewObject`. So `$scope.map['1']` is a different object between digest cycle 1 and 2 and so cycle 3 starts. Cycle 3 will differ from cycle 2 and so cycle 4 will start and so on ...